# Adding parameters to a .net events

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to add a parameter to a method created by Visual Studio but if I do I get this error log:

```
No overload for 'PortConfig_FormClosed' matches delegate 'FormClosedEventHandler'
```

Code:

```
    private void PortConfig_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e, PortSetup portSetupForm)
    {
        portSetupForm.refreshPorts();
    }
```

PortSetup is a class and refreshPorts is a method.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You cannot add parameters to an event. The best you can do at this stage is make portSetupForm a field, and use it directly.

Comment: I've tried that but it brings up a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error

Comment: Then you will need to assign the value of portSetupForm somewhere in your code, and check if portSetupForm is null in your event

Comment: You can't. C# expect event handlers to have a specific signature, whose parameters are populated by the class raising the event. What value would the extra parameter have if you could add it?

Comment: You can test if `sender` is a `PortSetup` form, cast it and access whatever you need on it

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this worked I really don't know why but it worked!:

```
    public void runRefreshPorts()
    {
        PortSetup ps = new PortSetup();
        ps.refreshPorts();
    }

    private void PortConfig_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        runRefreshPorts();
    }
```

Thanks anyways!